# Setear valores al "header" de un DrawerLayout en tiempo de ejecucón

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-drawerlayout

Tengo una consulta, estoy trabajando con *DrawerLayout* y estoy intentando "setear" los valores de tres TextView del *"header"* en tiempo de ejecución desde una clase *AsyncTask*, pero por algún motivo estos objetos no están mostrando los valores, estos datos lo estoy obteniendo desde una tabla en una BD Sqlite local y he validado que si obtengo información. Agradeceré su apoyo.

A continuación detallo parte del código

**activity_principal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/dwrMain"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/style_background">
    </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_main_drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer">        
  </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**header_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="130dp"
  android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtUserHeader"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    style="@style/FontTitleHeader"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtTitleHeader"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtTitleHeader"
    style="@style/FontSubTitleHeader"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtEmailHeader"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtEmailHeader"
    style="@style/FontSubTitleHeader"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Luego mi clase **PrincipalActivity.java**

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

  private String TAG = null;
  private FrameLayout frameLayout;
  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private NavigationView navigationView;
  private Toolbar toolbar;
  private TextView txtNameHeader;
  private TextView txtTitleHeader;
  private TextView txtEmailHeader;    

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
    initUI();
    synchronize();
  }

  private void synchronize() {
    SynchronizeService syncService = new SynchronizeService(PrincipalActivity.this);
    syncService.execute();        
  }

  private void initUI(){
    TAG = PlanVisitFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_fragment);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dwrMain);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtNameHeader = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.txtUserHeader);
    txtTitleHeader = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.txtTitleHeader);
    txtEmailHeader = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.txtEmailHeader);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.title_activity_principal, R.string.title_activity_principal);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.color.DrawerBackground, GravityCompat.START);
  }    
  ....

}
```

Mi clase **SynchronizeService.java** que es donde estoy realizando el "seteo"

```
public class SynchronizeService extends AsyncTask {

  private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
  private Context context;
  private Resources resources;
  private NavigationView navigationView;
  private TextView txtNameHeader;
  private TextView txtTitleHeader;
  private TextView txtEmailHeader;

  public SynchronizeService(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    this.resources = context.getResources();
  }

  protected void onPreExecute(){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.msg_sync_back));
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    SynchronizeBackend synchronizeBackend = new SynchronizeBackend(context);
    synchronizeBackend.getAllSynchronize();
    return null;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Object o){
    LoginController loginController = new LoginController(context);
    CollId collId = loginController.getValuesHeader(LoginPersistence.getUser());        

    //Aquí estoy realizando el seteo del header
    navigationView = (NavigationView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtNameHeader = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.txtUserHeader);
    txtTitleHeader = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.txtTitleHeader);
    txtEmailHeader = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.txtEmailHeader);
    txtNameHeader.setText(collId.getClName());
    txtTitleHeader.setText(collId.getClTitle());
    txtEmailHeader.setText(collId.getClMail());        

    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Se están conservando los valores anteriores o al agregarlos por medio del Asynctask se borran y no se agrega nada?

Comment: @Elenasys, no asigno valores iniciales, allí es cuando recién quiero asignarle los valores.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que los métodos del `Asynctask` deben ser sobreescritos, agregando   `@Override`, si no se agrega, esto provoca que no sean ejecutados:

```
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Object o){
  ...
  ...
  ...
  }
```

Comment: Elenasys coloque el @Override pero sigo igual, por algún motivo no se muestra la información.

Comment: Por favor, agrega un breakpoint dentro de onPostExecute(), y revisa si en verdad esta ejecutandose ese método.

Comment: Estoy agregando prints, y si lo ejecuta, es mas, estoy mostrando la información obtenida en consola. La verdad le sigo dando vueltas y no doy con el porque.

Answer (score 0):

Por curiosidad, podrías probar a ejecutar todo en el hilo principal de la aplicación.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                // Pon tu código aquí
            }
        });
```

Prueba y coméntanos que tal.